# Subprocess not raising CalledProcessError

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, exception, subprocess

I have a script that loops through a few file paths in order execute some other python and bash scripts using subprocess.

I know that these scripts will occasionally fail, and I want to catch the exception and stop the loop/exit the calling script.  This seems like it should be very simple – but I'm going nuts getting it to work.

I've tried a number of subprocess methods, and I can't seem to catch a CalledProcessError from *any* of them (`call`, `check_call`, `check_output` `Popen`).

```
# calling.py

for script in ['w', 'x', 'y']:
    try:
        subprocess.check_output('ipython {}.py'.format(script).split())
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print "Caught CalledProcessError"
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        print "Caught some other exception"
        raise
```

Now imagine the first script throws an exception. I want it to cause the calling script to exit.

```
# w.py

print "w"
a = {}
a[0]  # KeyError
```

Instead none of the exceptions are caught by the calling script and the calling script continues the loop.

```
$ ipython calling.py
w
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/h138124/git/exceptional/w.py in <module>()
      1 print "w"
      2 a = {}
----> 3 a[0]

KeyError: 0
x
y
```

Comment: Why are you using ipython to run the files? Also what OS?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm using ipython because the python install on the machine is out of date.  I'm logging into a name node on a cluster that I do no administer so I'm rolling with it. I get the same results with python.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham also same results on OS X and Windows 7.

Comment: how do you log in to the machine? I cannot replicate this on linux at all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I mistyped before.  I've run it on OS X and Linux (CentOS 6.6).  I'm logging in via ssh using cygwin from Windows 7 VM (I have to do it this way due to stupid Azure VPN client).

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue and started debugging into subprocess.py.

Than I realized that I never reached a breakpoint in the subprocess.run() function.

And than it came to my mind, that I did install the **subprocess.run** package for python35 a time ago.

After deleting the package it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `ipython` doesn't return a non-zero exit code on exceptions, which is required for `subprocess.check_output` to raise a `CalledProcessError`. Just use `python`.

```
$ cat test.py 
1/0
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
$ echo $?
1
$ ipython test.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/alexhall/Dropbox/python/sandbox/test.py in <module>()
----> 1 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
$ echo $?
0
```

Alternatively, just import the script or use `execfile` or something similar.

Comment: Interesting.  This is good to know – though It doesn't solve the problem. I get the same results using python (no exception is caught and the loop continues).

Comment: @conner.xyz can you replicate the results I have? Does python have a non-zero return code for scripts with exceptions?

Comment: yes I can replicate your results (python returns 1, ipython returns 0) but it doesn't affect the catching of exceptions when one script is running another.

Comment: Try `subprocess.call` and print the return value (it's supposed to be the exit code).

Comment: It's 0. Whether I use python or ipython.  It shows the KeyError but doesn't actual catch any exception.  This is bizarre.  I'm going to try and wrap callee scripts in main and import like you suggested.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if you have some weird `subprocess` issue. Can you get a non-zero return value for any other commands, e.g. `ls nonexistentthing`?

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough I wanted to do exactly what is happening to you, and I could not, because I was not using try except (I am in python 2.7).
What happen if you simply do that?

```
for script in ['w', 'x', 'y']:
    out = subprocess.check_output('ipython {}.py'.format(script).split())
    print(out)
```

As far as I can understand of this mysterious subprocess, if you want the program to stop you have to disentangle from the try except structure, as subprocess.check_output will stop by default when the exit status is 1.